# React Native Error: react-native@0.41.2 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get below error when trying to `npm install` on this project: https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip-app

```
tar: .libs.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
npm WARN react-native@0.41.2 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I can't figure out how to install React Native, the project is one year old and I guess I must somehow update to latest version?

Following guide from http://www.cnblogs.com/mmx8861/p/9150009.html I did:
n

```
pm cache clean
Modified package.json with: "react":"~15.4.1"; "react-native":"0.42.3"; "react-test-renderer":"15.4.1"
npm install all module
npm install
npm i react-native-maps@0.12.5 --S
react-native link react-native-maps
```

Manually changing to React16 results in :

```
npm WARN enzyme@2.9.1 requires a peer of react@0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-dom@15.6.2 requires a peer of react@^15.6.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package react is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Then I changed `"enzyme": "^2.9.1"` to `"enzyme": "^3.0.0"` and `"react-dom": "^15.6.0"` to `"react-dom": "^15.6.0"` and now I'm stuck at below:

```
npm WARN react-addons-perf@15.4.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-addons-test-utils@15.6.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-dom@15.6.2 requires a peer of react@^15.6.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package react is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

It seems according to [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html) the support for react-addons-perf is discontinued as of React 16 !

How do I fix the npm install errors?

Cheers

Comment: What is the question? The error is clear. All peers need to be updated

Comment: How to fix the error? npm install fails

Comment: Most obvious way would be to remove all of your deps and reinstall them if you keep getting errors. Note that unmet peer is a warning and not an error though. That means the install succeeded. Just keep at it.